# System will not login automatically to SMB server after login

Tags: release-juno, settings, system

I am new in the Linux world. I want to let elementary OS automatically login to my NAS after each reboot. Now I have to login manually after each reboot which is getting pretty annoying.

I connect through SMB (Windows share). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How do you connect to the NAS initially? I have a SMB share on a NAS that I connected to once via the default file manager, it prompted me for username and password, which I entered and ticked the "Remember" option and I haven't had to enter credentials since.

Comment: I opens the Files application and click on Connect to server. I then choose type, enters the local IP address and the password. I also checks remember the password. And almost each time I restarts my computer, I get no Internet. If I enable the internet, I must type in a password. Is that box for the connection to the NAS? If I enter my password for the login to elementary OS in that box, the box disappears and never come back

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the dialog asking for the password? That doesn't sound like it's asking for the NAS password.

Comment: Sure. Here it is: https://i.imgur.com/a4kq5I5.jpg. That window appears when I have restarted my computer and must manually connect to the internet (the slider for the wired connection is to the left). Worth noting is that I have enabled autoconnect to my VPN service.

Comment: This password prompt is nothing to do with SMB auth. Have you changed the password for your user account recently?

Comment: Nope. I haven't changed the password since I installed elementary OS few weeks ago